# load django form into template after initial page load

Tags: django

I created a django form and want to display it in a light box after someone clicks a button on my html page.  besides loading the form  on the initial page load, i also wanted to call the view which displays the form with javascript.  is there a way to only load the form template without reloading the entire webpage?  I want to do this incase there are errors on the form so that  I could just reload the lightbox with the form and error messages instead of the entire page.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Return just the HTML for the form from a separate view, then call the view via XHR. Once you've received the HTML, just replace what is already in the appropriate div.

Comment: Thanks Ignacio, i think you answered quite a few of my questions earlier as well.

Comment: btw, would the following be sufficient:     return render_to_response(addReviewForm.html,'{"form":form}, mimetype = "application/xhtml+xml")
or is there a way to do it via json?

Comment: Doing it with JSON means that you'd have to render the template using JavaScript. Better to use the template engine you already have than to add another somewhere else. I wouldn't use that mimetype though, since it's only a document fragment.

Comment: hi ignacio,  what mimetype should i use.  if i send over the response without one, wouldn't the browser render a new page?  thank..i'm pretty new to all this

Comment: XHR will never result in a new page being rendered as a side effect. `text/plain` should be fine.